# LINQ query with boolean check

Tags: c#, linq

I need a method which should return a list of stores from stores table, where customerid = id and Isactive = "true".

I am able to get the customerid match like so, how can I also include the Boolean check... need help with the query syntax..the "AND" operator

```
 private IList<Store> GetStores(int id)
    {
        var stlist = db.Stores.Where(m => m.CustomerId == id).ToList();
         return (stlist);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `Isactive` is a property of records in `db.Stores`, like `CustomerId` is

You can just add the additional check inside the `Where` extension method:

Assuming that `Isactive` is a property of type **`bool`**

```
private IList<Store> GetStores(int id)
{
    var stlist = db.Stores.Where(m => m.CustomerId == id && m.Isactive).ToList();
    return (stlist);
}
```

But if `Isactive` is a property of type **`string`** as OP seems to indicate

```
private IList<Store> GetStores(int id)
{
    var stlist = db.Stores.Where(m => m.CustomerId == id && m.Isactive == "true").ToList();
    return (stlist);
}
```

In `C#` and many other languages, `&&` is the Boolean AND operator.

Comment: edited because it's not clear if the `Isactive` property in question is a bool or string

Comment: Boolean operations are faster, so as a rule of thumb I'd recommend checking for boolean operations first (with the AND operator), as the second portion of the AND operator will not need to execute.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var stlist = db.Stores.Where(m => m.CustomerId == id && m.Isactive == "true").ToList();
```

Comment: Or `&& m.Isactive` :)

Comment: @PhilVallone I assume in question  he has mentioned a String Property

Comment: @Sajeetharan if that is the case, then the above code will fail as `true` as you have it written is not a string

Comment: Haha I see you assumed the same and changed your answer :)

Comment: Indeed. After re-reading OP's question, I realized it was not as obvious as it looked  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
    private IList<Store> GetStores(int id)
    { 
      var stlist = db.Stores.Where(m=>m.CustomerId == id && m.IsActive == true).ToList();
      return stlist;
    }
```